# Google App Engine oAuth Issue

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, oauth

I'm working on building an iPhone application and using Google AppEngine as the data storage.  I also need to have the ability to use oAuth for my users, but I can't even get oAuth to work at this moment on AppEngine.

Successful Demo:
http://twitteroauth.appspot.com/

Code powering that demo:
http://github.com/tav/tweetapp/blob/master/standalone/twitter_oauth_handler.py

The problem is that when I run the script on my account with my Twitter application information, it goes through the process successfully, but nothing happens.  It takes me to Twitter for the "allow or deny" page, but when I allow, it just reverts me back based on the callback URL without the page thinking I'm logged in.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the login page in twitter? If your question is about twitter not showing the login page then you are logged into twitter already. If your question is about twitter not showing allow or deny (authorization page) then you have already authorized the application. Twitter doesn't ask authorization question every time.